# WatchKit Extension undefined symbols error

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoapods, watchkit

I have an existing application with some library linked with cocoapod. And now I want to build a apple watch extension to it.
When I just add the WatchKit Extension target, everything goes fine. But if I try to create a helper function in my app(to be called by watch app). Even it is very sample:

```
Helper.h
+(void)test;
Helper.m
+(void)test{
}
```

and inside watchkit's interfacecontroller:

```
- (void)willActivate {
    [super willActivate];
    [Helper test];
}
```

and it shows the following error:

```
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/user/Development/@IOS/myApp/Pods/build/Debug-iphoneos'
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_Helper", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in InterfaceController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

is it something related to the cocoaPod setting??

Comment: Did you `#import "Helper.h` in your extension? Your class method declaration also shouldn't include `( )`.

Comment: thanks, but I did add the header and it is just a typo about the (  )

Comment: Were you able to solve this issue?